# Delphi XE2 Run with debugging very slow

Tags: delphi, debugging

Have just migrated my major project from D2010 to XE2 (Update 4). the project is around 100,000 lines of code, and 150+ forms all created automatically and lots of static data allocation (big arrays etc).  In D2010 when I hit F9 it compiles and is on the main screen in 5 seconds flat, in XE2 it compiles instantly but then takes about 40-50 seconds for the main screen to appear, also screen refreshing etc is painfully slow it feels like I'm on an RDP connection. I can live with it (just) but how do I get back my old debugging performance.

Note this does not affect the release version or running without debugging so please no answers telling me to optimise my app or create the forms at runtime as it runs like lightning outside the IDE, I'm hoping its just a checkbox I've missed somewhere.

tks guys (and gals)

Comment: That's not a lot of code. Could it be the large number of forms?

Comment: Do you have any conditional breakpoints set that could be taking a long time to evaluate?

Comment: IMHO I think your allocation on startup might be the culprit, how about some break points on each method that allocates memory or creates X number of forms, can you do that and come back with an edit?

Comment: No breakpoints are set., yes theres a lot of forms and memory allocation on startup but like I said already the application is very quick outside the debugger and under the D2010 debugger I'm looking for a specific answer to why Delphi XE2 debugger is slow. If nobody else is experiencing this problem I'm going to do a re-install of XE2 and my third-party components at the weekend and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @boz well, no one can tell you for sure why the debugger is slow, other than the people that are working on it, however, if I were to guess, it is probably related to the amount of memory used by the debugger on top of what your application is allocating + extra checks and so on. What I don't understand is why migrating a project from D2010(a very good product, has it's flaws but from what I understand it's more stable than XE2) to XE2 which haven't prove it's stability yet, that's just my view, **new isn't always better**.

Comment: Have you truly re-built all units cleanly?  You mention that the old one 'built in 5 seconds' and the new one builds 'instantly', which implys that it hasn't ever been truly re-built from scratch in XE2.  Have you cleaned all old files and done a true *full* Re-build All in Debug Build?  This has certainly been the source of similar problems for me in other IDEs - i.e. the IDE 'remembering' somthing from a previous build which is now corrupted.

Comment: New isnt always better - agreed

Comment: All units rebuilt using the project - build all project, no difference unfortunately.. Thinking a re-install is the best way to fix this though the Delphi XE2 Update 4 already did this :-(

Comment: I hope that might help with further research. I have just fixed it based on the comments on the following link: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/delphi-why-is-the-debugger-so-slow/

I had the MDM (Machine Debug Manager) running on my services and after stopping it, the debug is back to normal.

I did not get deep into the investigations to understand the root cause.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the ide fix pack http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack-2009-10/
It's a 3rdparty dll that patches the IDE at runtime (doesn't affect your apps) and fixes some performance issues and bugs.

Comment: Hi I tried that when I asked question in Embacadero forum, speeded up the IDE startup a bit but did not see any other effects.

Comment: Have you upgraded any components with the move to Xe2?  e.g. FastMM, exception handlers?  Could the configuration of those be doing more checks than previously, slowing down the startup in debug?

Comment: hi using two 3rd party components reportbuilder and mydac. I do not have source to either but the performance problem extends to units which do not use these. (Its like I've got a sleep(1); procedure between every line of code ! )

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
A collegue of mine as well with MS Office. The problem there was a drive that was connected to his profile, but could no longer be found.
When i closed my computer i saw DExplorer hanging and thought of the problem my collegue was having (Explorer and drive). My wife was sitting next to me today and for days, when she was not, my Delphi IDE was very, very slow. Today it ran like sunshine again. And sure enough when she left the computer, delphi was slow again. I disabled the link i had to that computer and Delphi runs smooth again.

Answer (score 3):

I had something similar with my XE3 IDE, for me turning off the Windows Messages in event log solved the problem.

```
Tools -> Options -> Debugger Options -> Event Log -> uncheck Windows Messages under Messages.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your codes only, do not compile/build with library debug dcu.

Hope this help

Comment: hi. the project compiler debug.dcu option is not checked